# Change table users in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I've created a new table called "admins" table. I want to use this instead of the users table.

I've already added this in my User model:

```
protected $table = 'admins';
```

And I also tried this on my auth.php:

```
         'users' => [
         'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'admins',
     ],
```

But none of them worked. Are there any other solutions that could work?

Comment: This is where the concept of `groups` or `roles` comes into play. All Users are "Users", but not all Users are "Admins". You can either use something as simple as a `boolean: is_admin` on your `users` table, or as complex as linking `groups` to `users`. See https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0 for an example.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. Thanks for introducing me to sentinel :)

Comment: This should help https://www.5balloons.info/changing-authentication-table-laravel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you must also change the `RegisterController`, in it you will find the `create` method:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

As you can see it too uses the `User` model.